# Scan the entire folder during file saving

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I installed the [Go extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.go) for VS Code. This extension installed the following packages:

```
gocode: /Users/oleg/go/bin/gocode installed
gopkgs: /Users/oleg/go/bin/gopkgs installed
go-outline: /Users/oleg/go/bin/go-outline installed
go-symbols: go-symbols not installed
guru: guru not installed
gorename: /Users/oleg/go/bin/gorename installed
gotests: gotests not installed
gomodifytags: gomodifytags not installed
impl: impl not installed
fillstruct: fillstruct not installed
goplay: goplay not installed
godoctor: godoctor not installed
dlv: /Users/oleg/go/bin/dlv installed
gocode-gomod: /Users/oleg/go/bin/gocode-gomod installed
godef: /Users/oleg/go/bin/godef installed
goreturns: /Users/oleg/go/bin/goreturns installed
golint: /Users/oleg/go/bin/golint installed
```

I have a directory where I just save my code sketches for testing and when I simply save changes to the file (`command+s`) see the following messages in the OUTPUT console of VS Code.

```
Starting linting the current package at /Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example
Starting "go vet" under the folder /Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example
Starting building the current package at /Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example
Not able to determine import path of current package by using cwd: /Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example and Go workspace: 
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example>Finished running tool: /Users/oleg/go/bin/golint
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example/function_time.go:8:1 exported function Time should have comment or be unexported

/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example>Finished running tool: /Users/oleg/App/go/bin/go build -o /var/folders/7y/rhj_y5j12sjb900l6pk9wxpw0000gp/T/vscode-goHFXY40/go-code-check .
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example/test.go:7:6 main redeclared in this block
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example/arrays.go:7:6 main redeclared in this block
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example/test2.go:7:6 main redeclared in this block
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example/test3.go:7:6 main redeclared in this block

/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example>Finished running tool: /Users/oleg/App/go/bin/go vet .
/Users/oleg/Documents/programming/go/example/3.go:7:6 main redeclared in this block
```

As far as I understand, every time I save file `go vet` is automatically started, and checks all my files in the directory with the open file (not sure about that: then tries to build a package from all the files in the directory).
I just want to check errors only in an open file, which I'm working on now, and not check the entire directory or something else.

Can anyone explain how to do this and in general what happens when I press `command+s`?

Comment: You can't meaningfully check errors only in the open file. It only makes sense to scan the entire package, since the contents of other files in the package can mean that your current file is incorrect.

Comment: To be more explicit: suppose you're editing `main.go`, and it tries to call `foo()`, which is defined in another file, but the same package. If you're only checking one file, it will report an undefined function error. Another example: Maybe `main.go` defines `foo()`, and so does `foo.go`, in the same package. If you only check `main.go`, you won't detect an error, but if you scan the entire package, you'll get an error for duplicate definitions.

Comment: @Flimzy Thanks for the explanation. I agree, it makes sense.

What about "Starting linting the current package at" and "Starting building the current package at", is this also from `go vet`?

Comment: @KarlsD no, that's because it's set to build on save.

Comment: @Adrian Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: It should be an option in the VSCode Go extension settings.